# How do I inspect what was the last failed job in Resque?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I know it returns a hash, but its strange how the syntax goes.. I'm trying to find out what the last one is.

If I do this :

```
Resque.info[:failed] # -> 68
```

So assuming there's 68 failed jobs, when I do this :

```
Resque::Failure.all()
```

It only returns one job ( I believe its the first job ).

I think this is just a syntactical error on my part. Because I've also seen this :

```
Resque::Failure.all(0, 20)
```

Which I believe would pull an array of indices between 0 and 20.

So.. anyone know the syntactical clause to pull just the last failed job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `Resque::Failure.all(0, 20)` you will give 1st param as the start point and second param as the number of results.

```
Resque::Failure.all(0, 1)
```

is the correct syntax to get the last failure, if they are ordered DESC

EDIT:

They are ordered ASC, so:

```
Resque::Failure.all((Resque::Failure.count - 1), 1)
```

Comment: Hmm.. mine don't seem to be ordered by DESC so that would return the oldest failure.. Then using the doc logic, if I have "70" Failures, and I do `Resque::Failure.all(70, 1), it still returns nothing.

Comment: try `Resque::Failure.all(69, 1)` because it starts from 0

Comment: Strangely, `Resque::Failure.all(20,1)` was the *last* one. ?:D

Comment: yes, strangely. because i have your same issue. Resque.info[:failed] returns me 6, but from the resque web interface i can only see 1 error. ...documenting more....

Comment: Sorry, I'm reopening this as it seems count doesn't increment where the Failures do increment, and where the number is relative to the error that I can find, it doesn't actually log the error its representing in `Resque.info[:failure]`

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way to see resque job information. Resque comes with a Sinatra-based front end for seeing what's up with your queue. [image]

[Here](https://github.com/resque/resque#the-front-end) you will get detail information. Hope this will help someone.